# How can i get the progress each of the files upload with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, progress-bar, firebase-storage

i have this code to upload files to firebase database

```
export const upload = (
  name
) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const ref = firebaseApp.storage()
      ref
        .put(file)
        .then(snapshot => {
```

how can i get the progress each of the files? because i need to know the progress to display in a progressBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to `storageRef.put(file)` uploads a single file. As shown in the documentation on [monitoring upload progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress), you can track progress with:

```
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/rivers.jpg').put(file);

// Register three observers:
// 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
// 2. Error observer, called on failure
// 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
  (snapshot) => {
    // Observe state change events such as progress, pause, and resume
    // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
    var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
    console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
    switch (snapshot.state) {
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
        console.log('Upload is paused');
        break;
      case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
        console.log('Upload is running');
        break;
    }
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, 
  () => {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
    uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    });
  }
);
```

So in your case, you capture the task that `put` returns:

```
  const storageRef = firebaseApp.storage().ref(`${name}`)
  const task = storageRef.put(file)
```

And then you add the `on('stage_changed'` listener to that, just like the code from the docs does.

The third callback for `on('state_changed')` gets called when the upload has completed, so in there you'd do the same as in your current `then()` callback.